# eCommerce Cart Bug

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cart

I'm trying to fix a bug on a clients website, you cannot seem to successfully delete products from the cart, it initially disappears, but when you refresh the page, the item still shows in the cart.

Here is the site: http://www.dapperjacs.co.uk/

I have disabled all of the other plugins and cleared the cache of the WP eCommerce plugin, but still no luck.

Brad

Answer (score 0):

just visited your url, it seems to be working now...
as regards to ur other question of cart not gettin empty  after purchase [Wordpress/Woocommerce Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265809/wordpress-woocommerce-sessions/24486541)
update ur status after the trying out the answers over there...