# Wordpress/Woocommerce Sessions

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

Good afternoon, I have built a website for me client using Wordpress/Woocommerce. the site works great but one problem is that the basket/session doesn't clear after the order is finished. It looks to me that WooCommerce doesn't even have the feature as standard. Working with the Woocommece standard files, whats the best way to kill a session after the checkout process is complete?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: WooCommerce certainly clears the shopping cart(basket) after the order  is paid for - have a look at [this line of code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/bb787ff8cc8dd1754dca7035c4b2443dc0229f56/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L138) to confirm. If the order status is "failed" then it will not empty the cart - so if you are using PayPal or something and not completing the paypal checkout then it will flag this way and not empty the cart.

Answer (score 6):

Your cart should be clearing after checkout so something else may be wrong.

You could create a function with `empty_cart()` in it that is triggered when payment is complete "just in case".
See: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'pg_woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 10, 2 );
function pg_woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status ( $order_status, $order_id ) {

    $global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user this hook :

```
function custom_empty_cart( $order_id, $data ) {
   // delete current cart item here
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_empty_cart', 11, 2 );
```

Or you can check woocommerce hook list from [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).

Answer (score 0):

The cart should empty as this feature is standard, empty_cart();

Are you using any cache-plugins? In that case you need to exclude the cart page
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/

It could also be a problem with the payment-gateway, make sure you have updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

i found a similar question but it clears the cart on the click of a button..
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-an-empty-cart-button-to-cart-page seems to have worked for some user..
here is the code , it should go in to the function.php file

```
add_action('init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if( isset($_REQUEST['clear-cart']) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

this is the code for the button

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="clear-cart" value="<?php _e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce'); ?>" />
```

im guessing u dont need  a button, so in the next page when u want the cart to be empty, u can explicitly call this function _e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce');

for example if it you would like to clear the cart in a post page whose title is Payment Success

```
if(is_single('Payment Success'))
_e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce');
```

or if its slug is payment-success

```
is_single('payment-success');
_e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce');
```

similarly to check if its homepage you can use

```
is_front_page();
```

or if its on the wordpress page u can use this

```
if(is_page( 'Payment Success' ))
    _e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce');

if(is_page( 'payment-success' ))
    _e('Empty Cart', 'woocommerce');
```

you can include the above code in the head section of your wordpress site!!

Hope this helps